# How to show if $x,y$ are vectors, $|x - y | \le |x| + |y| $

Tags: vector-spaces

How do I show this inequality: $|x  - y | \le |x| + |y| $?

Somehow use the triangle inequality?

Comment: $x - y = x + (-y)$

Comment: Oh wow..but thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apply triangle inequality for the vectors $\vec{x}$ and $-\vec{y}$ and recall that $\Vert -y \Vert = \Vert y \Vert$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray}
|x-y| &\le & |x|+   |-y|&=& |x| + |y|
\end{eqnarray}