# prove $|X-Y|\le|X|+|Y|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

MY question is how to prove $|X-Y|\le|X|+|Y|$.

My textbook proves another version of triangular inequality, which is

$|A|-|B|\le|A-B|$ by substituting X=A-B and Y=B into $|X+Y|\le|X|+|Y|$,

but it leaves the above version as an exercise, and I can't solve it.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Just substitute $\,Y \mapsto -Y\,$ in the triangle inequality.

Comment: Oh.. so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610003/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165396/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/962332/42969

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality $$|X|+|Y|=|X|+|-Y|\geq|X+(-Y)|=|X-Y|.$$